# Get list values with @form in Play Java

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2.2.6 project I pass custom form QuestionForm to scala.html. In html, I access QuestionForm values (i.e. list in QuestionForm class named incorrect) with `'@form("incorrect[0]").value'`

However, instead of a constant I would like to pass variable i to @form:

```
@for(i <- 0 to 10) {
   <input type="text" name="incorrect[]" id="incorrect-@i" value='@form("incorrect[i]").value()'/>
}
```

but value stays empty this way. I also tried `@form("incorrect[@i]").value()` and various other syntax solutions, but none of them give results.

Could someone please explain how to why the solution in code doesn't work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want either:

```
@form("incorrect[" + i + "]")
```

or:

```
@form(s"incorrect[$i]")
```

it can be confusing in Java Play apps because Twirl uses Scala-like syntax.